# Hermitian transpose of cell array

Tags: matlab

I have stored four images in cell array as 4 by 1 matrix. How to perform hermitian transpose of this matrix in matlab and then to perform this matrix with its hermitian transpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another possibility is to use [cellfun](http://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html) to avoid the `for` loop:

```
images = {rand(4,4)+i*rand(4,4), rand(4,4)+i*rand(4,4)};
images_h = cellfun(@ctranspose, images, 'UniformOutput', 0);
```

Then if you want to perform element-wise multiplication:

```
images_a = cellfun(@mtimes, images, images_h, 'UniformOutput', 0)
```

Comment: `cellfun` is technically a `for` loop under the hood, but I agree that this is cleaner.

Comment: Yes, and I would also add a disclaimer, that `cellfun` is also usually slower that a `for` loop...

Comment: Correct on all accounts.

Answer (score 1):

The [Hermitian transpose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_transpose) is the conjugate transpose. So you can use the [' operator](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ctranspose.html#buaudse-6):

```
imageT = image'
```

If you have the cell array with four images, you can do:

```
images = {image1, image2, image3, image4}
imagesT = cell(size(images))
for ii = 1:numel(images)
  imagesT{ii} = images{ii}';
end
```

Comment: @tashuhka....thank you for your help. Sir can you help me how to perform multiplication of this matrix with its hermitian and save as 4 by 4 matrix for each pixel.

Comment: @Lalu If this solution helped you, please mark it as valid answer. If you have further questions, please create a new Question for each individual issue. Thank you.